# Monospaced serif font on Android

Tags: android, fonts

Is there any standard **monospaced serif** font on Android?  I can find a monospaced sans-serif, but no luck with a serif.

If there is one, what is it?

Comment: Is the monospaced sans-serif font to which you refer 'Droid Sans Mono', or is it something else?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I'm looking for a *serif* font.  The Droid Sans Mono is a great *sans serif* font though.

Comment: Sorry, my comment should have been more clear.  I was just wondering if the monospaced sans-serif font you found was 'Droid Sans Mono' (I'm looking for a monospaced sans-serif and a monospaced serif).

Comment: @RockPaperLizard For Android I think that Droid Sans Mono is the best monospaced font to use.  Even outside of Android, the Droid fonts are fantastic.

Comment: Thanks John!  I agree that those fonts are very well composed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is no, I believe Droid **Sans** Mono is the only monospaced font available in the platform. See:

```
android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-17/data/fonts/system_fonts.xml
```

And

```
android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-17/data/fonts/fonts.mk
```

You can, of course, roll your own.

Answer (score 3):

You can always choose to use your own font. Just place the font file in the assets folder, and use the following code

```
Typeface requestedTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontFileName);
```

**For HTML5 app**

You can use **[Google Web Font API](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/)** to render across browsers. Droid Serif font is available in Google Web Fonts API.

Comment: This is for a HTML5 app, and not a native app.  So it gets a little more problematic if there isn't one built in.